# Making 7" display work for OpenWrt

Tags: pi-2, display, openwrt

I have a 7" 800 x 480 touch display connected via the internal display connector (DSI) of my Rasperry Pi 2. The display is automatically recognized by Raspbian.

When I boot OpenWrt, the display remains dark and I have to connect a HDMI monitor to see the command prompt.

Is it possible to make the display work in OpenWrt as well?

I want to be able to configure OpenWrt via the command prompt and perhaps display a few of the main setting or statistic with the display.

Comment: SSH is a better solution.

Comment: @M.Rostami: yes, if I always carry a Laptop with me, that would be possible. As a programmer, I don't have issues with that. However, I want it for a more noobish use. The RPi shall work in a standalone mode and e.g. display connection settings (WLAN SSID and password, bandwidth and usage% and possibly a button to disconnect/reconnect)

Comment: Alright, I agree with you and it's a great idea. I have a question, How can I achieve this idea with a normal monitor which is connected by a VGA cable? I think I need to install a GUI package